# Why vue router reloads the component, when this component is the same, but the target route is defined in another children level?

Tags: vue-router

Many people have a question: How to reload the component when the route is changed, but the component is the same?.

I have the opposite problem. The component is refreshed, when the "to" route is in different children level then the "from" route.

Vue router 3.0.6.

This is for replacing from route BusinessCaseDetailInsert to route BusinessCaseDetail:

```js
this.$router.replace({ name: 'BusinessCaseDetail', params: { id: newData.BusinessCaseId } });
```

1) The component is not refreshed, when the "to" and "from" route is in the same level. It is desirable.

```js
var businessCaseDetailRoutes = [
    {
        path: 'business-case-detail-:id',
        name: 'BusinessCaseDetail',
        component: () => import('@/components/panels/businesscases/businesscase-detail'),
        props: (route) => getBusinessCaseDetailProps(route)
    },
    {
        path: 'business-case-insert',
        name: 'BusinessCaseDetailInsert',
        component: () => import('@/components/panels/businesscases/businesscase-detail')
    }
];
```

2) The component is refreshed, when the "to" and "from" route is not in the same level. It is not desirable. :-(

```js
var businessCaseDetailRoutes = [
    {
        path: 'business-case-detail-:idbc',
        component: '<router-view></router-view>',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                name: 'BusinessCaseDetail',
                component: () => import('@/components/panels/businesscases/businesscase-detail'),
                props: (route) => getBusinessCaseDetailProps(route)
            },
            {
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'business-case-insert',
        name: 'BusinessCaseDetailInsert',
        component: () => import('@/components/panels/businesscases/businesscase-detail')
    }
];
```

I need to avoid the refreshing the component, when the target route is defined in different children level.